# Opencv with fedora 23 Qt: The program has unexpectedly finished

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

> The program has unexpectedly finished. Starting
>   /home/tamercan/build-myfirst2-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/myfirst2...
>   /home/tamercan/build-myfirst2-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/myfirst2
>   crashed.

This is my main.cpp

```
#include <opencv2/core/base.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/mat.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/types.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect_c.h>
#include <opencv2/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the video camera no. 0



    namedWindow("MyVideo",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "MyVideo"
    // Load Face cascade (.xml file)
        CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
        face_cascade.load( "xml/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml" );

    while (1)
    {
        Mat frame;

        bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video

         if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
        {
             cout << "Cannot read a frame from video stream" << endl;
             break;
        }
         // Detect faces
             std::vector<Rect> faces;
             face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );

             // Draw circles on the detected faces
             for( int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ )
             {
                 Point center( faces[i].x + faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].y + faces[i].height*0.5 );
                 ellipse( frame, center, Size( faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].height*0.5), 0, 0, 360, Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), 4, 8, 0 );


                     imshow( "Detected Face", frame );
             }



                 //rectangle( frame, center, Size( faces[i].width*2, faces[i].height*2), Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ) );




        if (waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
       {
            cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
            break;
       }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

My .pro file is

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = myfirst2
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

QMAKE_DEFAULT_INCDIRS="" && make

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/
LIBS += -L/usr/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_video -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_ml -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect
```

Comment: Check that `face_cascade` is not null. I bet you passed an invalid path to the xml file. Using a debugger and find the exact error will help a lot

Comment: I didnt try to debug.When i add opencv library to my project it crashes.It works normally.xml file is not null also.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by adding the paths to *opencv's bin* and *lib* files to `PATH`:

[image]

Comment: You have a unique style of answering. It makes it very easy to spot that you are posting the same answer identically to multiple questions. Please do not do that.